# Serialization: DateTime.Now VS DateTime from database

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, datetime

**Context:** I'm serializing some data that includes a date of which I need to display milliseconds. I'm using a XmlSerializer to write an XML file. I'm taking some data from a database using a DataTable.

**What I'm actually doing:** I cast the date in this way

```
CDate(dr("MyDate")).ToUniversalTime()
```

But once serialized this does not includes milliseconds.

While trying some workarounds I've found out that serialize in the same way

```
DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()
```

does includes milliseconds.

**Actual question:** what should I do to include milliseconds while serializing dr("MyDate")?

Please note that answers in VB.NET or C# are both well accepted.

Comment: what database are you using and what datatype has the column MyDate

Comment: Database: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 SP1; Column: DateTime2(3)

Comment: If it's any use to you, if you're using SQL Server, you can also use [`FOR XML`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) to do a lot of the work for you.

Comment: you should use DateTime2(7) to store more precision datetime values. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I'm using DateTime2(3) because I cannot get more accurate data from the feed that goes into the database.

Comment: Time on a PC can be displayed down to 100nsec (1 tick) either from database of c#.  You can use the ToString() method to format time.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked, what CDate contains? For exmaple [Definition of CDate](http://robm.fastmail.fm/articles/date_class.html) shows that CDate contains only seconds, not milliseconds. When the original time in the database is stored in text format (with milliseconds) you should use DateTime.TryParseExact(...) to get the complete time value. Otherwise, when the database itself uses another DateTime-class, you should use this type directly to convert to datetime.

Comment: You are providing a link to a C++ reference. By the way, I'm sure CDate includes milliseconds because CDate(dr("MyDate")).ToString("o") actually shows me milliseconds.